# How to re-enable jQuery tooltip after disabled = true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tooltip

Trying to temporarily disable the jQuery tooltip

```
$(document).tooltip( "option", "disabled", true );
```

When I try to re-enable them again, all of the `title` attributes are gone. I was trying to re-enable them using:

```
$(document).tooltip( "option", "disabled", false);
```

The `title` attributes is actually being removed completely when i first set it to `disabled` to `true`.

Also tried:

```
$(document).tooltip("disable");
$(document).tooltip("enable");
```

It is doing the same thing...

**Update**

Found a solution to my own question with the help of Jasen and zgr024. See [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24707759/1009046).

Comment: when you re-enable the tooltips should continue working.. http://jsfiddle.net/D8gMy/

Comment: This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMxqg/2/) does _not_ continue to work with jquery v2.1.0 and ui v1.11. What version of the libraries are you using? This looks a bug.

Comment: jQuery v1.11.1
jQuery UI - v1.11.0

Comment: It looks like I've reproduce the same issue using your first example.
I switch the fiddle to use external source `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js` and 
`http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js`. Initially it works, but once I hit disable, i get the same issue. The `title` attribute is being removed from the element also.

Comment: you will need to re-add the title attribute since the disabled flag is using removeAttr('title')... try setting it a variable before the disable so you can add it back... but yea its kinda stupid

Comment: Yes, insert a `.attr("title", "")` back into the element right after you disable. You don't even need to know the original title value -- just need the bare `title` attribute for it to work. See http://jsfiddle.net/xMxqg/3/.

Comment: Ok this is indeed stupid, but is there other workaround? `$(document).tooltip("disable");` essentially removed ALL my `title` attributes from EVERY elements. I can't just mass add a `title` back, especially `$(document).attr("title", "");` won't do it... this is going to be a performance hit too.

Comment: Short of using a different version you could add a class to these so you can get them all with one line `$(".stupid-tooltips").attr("title", "")`.

Comment: @Jasen something is still not right.. I just tried it out using the old jQuery 1.9.1 and UI 1.9.2, and it still have the same issue.

Comment: Have you removed the reference to the other versions?

Comment: @Jasen Yes. But I am going to drop the older jQuery, and try to make it work with the new libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So with the help of others above, I finally found a better solution. That require no brutal fix to re-adding `title` to every single elements. Don't get me wrong, that fix will work, but performance is important (especially I still need to support IE8 ugh).

Basically I add a custom variable to the tooltip object, this can also be a global variable. Since everything is an `Object` in js, you can just add anything you want to it.

```
$(document).tooltip.temporarilyOff
```

Then when I initialize the jQuery tooltip, I just need to add a check in the `open`:

```
var settings = {};
settings.tooltipClass = "tooltip";
settings.open = function (event, ui) {
    if ($(document).tooltip.temporarilyOff) {
        ui.tooltip.stop().remove();
    }
};
$(document).tooltip(settings);
```

Then when I need to temporarily disable the jQuery tooltip, I just need to toggle the flag anywhere I want. Like so:

```
$(document).tooltip.temporarilyOff = true;
```

Anything after this point, the tooltip won't be triggered, and all the elements will keep their `title` attributes. When I am done with what I am doing, I just need to set the flag back to `false` and tooltip will work exactly like before.

I can probably make this into jQuery plugin for easier calls and also hide the slightly ugly variable name... but anyway that's the idea. I think this is a much better fix as it won't force jQuery to remove the `title` attribute for nothing, then adding it back afterward doing twice the useless work.

Here is the [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/totszwai/M8WqG/1/) forked from @Jasen's original jsFiddle:

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a bug with the jquery version so you need a work-around to insert the **title** attribute after disabling tooltips.

Use a class name on the tooltip element you need re-enabled or use the `[title]` attribute selector.

```
<input type="text" class="tooltip-hack" title="tooltip text" />

$("#disable").on("click", function (e) {
    var tooltips = $("[title]");  // or $(".tooltip-hack")
    $(document).tooltip("disable");
    tooltips.attr("title", "");
});
```

Use the least destructive of the two depending on your html structure.

Also, you note that *all* title attributes are removed so be more selective with your tooltip.

```
// instead of
$(document).tooltip();

// use a more restrictive selector
$(".tooltip-hack").tooltip();
```

Working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMxqg/4/)

Comment: Is there a way to access/modify the global jquery.ui.tooltip object? I want to modify the `open` dynamically.

Comment: You can use `.tooltip({ open: function(e, ui){} })` then you can specify a function to run. If you need more help with that you should open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Codenamezero is a nice example of extending an object in jQuery/js but you can do this out-of-the-box:

```
$(document).tooltip("disable").tooltip("hide"); 

$(document).tooltip("enable").tooltip("show");
```

I have validation where this method can be useful to override defaults

Comment: That's cool, is this new? I don't recall having that function few years ago hehe... Thanks for the tip!